# React login with firebase async issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, stateless

to my problem. I created an App with react and a firebase login. Now I want to check my component if the user is logged in already, only then the render function should render the content.

I thought it would be nice to do this check in the componentDidMount lifecycle method, but it doesnt work, because the connection with firebase is async and the render function is called before the check with firebase is completed

```
componentDidMount() {
  firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    //do stuff
  }.bind(this));
}
```

it would be easy to set a state but I want to keep many components as possible stateless in my project. How can I solve the problem without adding a state to the component.

Comment: You'll have to keep this indication *somewhere*, either in the component or somewhere else. Depends on the scale of your project, you could have a central state with Redux. In this case the state will be kept externally and mapped to the components through props, so they could be stateless.